# Test cases are not running in JUnit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, testng

DateAdapterTest is the test class for DateAdapter which is responsible to test marshalling/unmarshalling the date type into String data type and it's vise versa. Test cases are not running.

```
  public class DateAdapterTest {
        /* Date adapter is a class to marshall date type into String and unmarshall  
         viseversa.
        */

    DateAdapter dateAdapter;

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "2014-01-01";
    private static final LocalDate DATE = new LocalDate(2014, 01, 01);

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        dateAdapter = new DateAdapter();
    }

    /*
     * @param Date Date type  
     * @return String String data type date
     * @throw Exception 
   */
    @Test
    public void testMarshal() throws Exception{

        String dateString = dateAdapter.marshal(DATE) ;
        assertEquals(DATE_FORMAT, dateString);      
    }

    /*
     * @param String String data type  
     * @return date LocalDate type date
     * @throw Exception 
    */
    @Test
    public void testUnmarshal() throws Exception{

        LocalDate date = dateAdapter.unmarshal(DATE_FORMAT);
        assertEquals(DATE , date);
    }

}
```

getting output as

```
===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: What are you using to run the test... maven, eclipse, ant?

Comment: @Fede's comment is very important, and probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Using JUnit/TestNG, maven 2.2, eclipse juno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed to durron597 comment. Your problem seems to be related to the way you are running your test and your junit test configuration.

If you are using Eclipse try right click on a test method and press on `Run JUnit Test` just to check if your test runs well. If it does it then you have a configuration problem for them.

By the way, add more details about what tool are you using to run your JUnit tests and I'll update the answer according to it.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno, JUnit, maven 2.2 versions.
As i've right clicked on test case mathod and getting the output as above. JUnit configuration is correct for other Test class.